# Phalcon PHP not routing for subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have one website, let's call it www.main.com, which is located on the server at /home4/username/public_html/main. This site is running Phalcon PHP with no issues at all.

Now I have made a subdomain, let's call it test.main.com, and used cPanel to set the route for the subdomain to /home4/username/testsite/test. This is where the problem is.

Both /public_html and /testsite have their own .htaccess files containing the following:

test site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ test/public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  ((?s).*) test/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

main site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule  ^$ main/public/    [L]
  RewriteRule  ((?s).*) main/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And testing the test site locally via XAMPP it works fine (currently just a very VERY simple Phalcon test page). But when I upload the exact same site to the server phalcon errors with: 
`PhalconException: IndexController handler class cannot be loaded`

The dispatch index.php file for the (non-working) test subdomain site contains the following:

```
<?php

try {
    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
       '../app/controllers/',
       '../app/models/'
    ))->register();

    //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function(){
       $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
       $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
       return $view;
    });

    //Setup a base URI
    $di->set('url', function(){
       $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
       $url->setBaseUri('/test/');
       return $url;
    });

    //Handle the request
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
    echo "<br /><br /><strong>Trace Stack</strong>: ", $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Now this is baffling, as I said, there's no reason code wise the Phalcon project is wrong, as it works fine locally. So the only thing I can think of is somehow the routing of the subdomain is screwing things up, but I have no idea how, or how to fix it?

Comment: Make `/home4/username/testsite/test/public/php_info.php` with code `<php? php_info(); ?>` to check if apache gets it at all.

Comment: @Tpojka I've done that. And when I then go to the URL for that site: `test.main.com/php_info.php` the php info page shows fine.

Comment: Could be `RewriteBase` problem. I see you didn't include it in `.htaccess` files but only one (from what we know - main) is set by default in apache. Try something with that - setting rewrite base?

Comment: @Tpojka I've added `RewriteBase /` to the `.htaccess` file and nothing changes. The base route seems okay seen as I put the phpinfo() page that you suggested in the /test/public/php_info.php page, and it maps to that no problem from the browser.

Comment: Can't tell much. I can only advice you to post same question on phalconphp forums.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be something really simply stupid. For some reason using phalcon locally via XAMPP on Windows allowed me to use `indexController.php` as a controller name. However, when uploaded to the Apache server the name needed to be capitalised in full camel case to `IndexController.php` to work.